# I have a flow that is running twice so i get two emails and am not sure where the issue is

Tags: power-automate, flow

I have a flow that is running twice.  As soon as i put the details on the form, the flow is running twice exactly at the same time and am not sure how to troubleshoot this to find which step is causing the issue?? Am suspecting its in the condition step... I did not design this flow and i don't want to break it either. So wondering if there is a way to troubleshoot the steps in the flow.

[image]

Comment: Is the flow being triggered twice, or is it just sending two emails? There are two send email activities in your flow setup, do they both send the same thing? Also, what is the trigger for your flow?

Comment: It shows as running twice after putting in the details... it seems its triggered twice when i view the flow runs

Comment: What is the trigger used in this flow?

Comment: Its the first step on the flow...have added a screenshot on this post of the trigger

Comment: So it's a Microsoft Forms form submission that is the trigger? I'll update my answer with a link to a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To troubleshoot your flow, you should be able to click into a flow run (from the Power Automate portal) and take a look at the steps that were executed, along with the data within each step.

**Update:** A similar issue has been reported in the past on Microsoft's Power Automate forum. Seems like the solution might be to switch the flow off/on, regenerate either the form, or the flow, or perhaps both.

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/One-Form-submission-triggering-Flow-twice/td-p/838267